# Are Module Names Consdiered to be Lowercase in Zend Framework?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-framework3

With the first version of Zend Framework *modules* were introduced. By *bootstrapping* their *Controllers* the **module name** by the definition in the code must not be explicitly lowercase only, however I have the strong assumption that these module names (in the end directory components of a path) are to be considered lowercase only.

I'd like to learn from Zend Framework regulars, be it ZF1 only and/or the later iterations what the commonality regarding the case of upper-/lower-/snake-/riddle-/camel-/whatever-case *module names* in Zend Framework is.

Feel free to show your best bet or any story about that matter.

Comment: Posix filesystems are traditionally case-sensitive and many of the early ZF1 based applications have lowercase directory names for the modules. With PSR-1 and PSR-2 directory components with at least an uppercase first letter became more prominent. Did this had any influence on naming modules w/ Zend Framework?